calling instance when promise resolves works one way but not another
I'm trying to load a PDF URL using Apryse's webViewer method. When I use the method as specified in their docs it works as intended (as shown below). But I don't want to initialize a new webViewer every function call so I tried to initialize webViewer once and call loadDocument() on the instance but that doesn't work. I don't get any errors or anything. What am I doing wrong?
Function calling:
loadDocViewer('https://pdfobject.com/pdf/sample.pdf')

Doesn't work:
let webViewerInstance;

WebViewer({
    path: '/@pdftron/webviewer/public',
}, document.getElementById('doc-viewer'))
    .then(instance => {
        webViewerInstance = instance
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error initializing WebViewer:', error);
    });

function loadDocViewer(url) {
    if (!webViewerInstance) {
        console.error('Doc Viewer is not initialized! Try again in a bit.');
        return;
    }

    webViewerInstance.UI.loadDocument(url);
}

Works:
function loadDocViewer(url) {
    WebViewer({
        path: '/@pdftron/webviewer/public',
    }, document.getElementById('doc-viewer'))
        .then(instance => {
            instance.UI.loadDocument(url);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error initializing WebViewer:', error);
        });
}


Perhaps it's this problem, you're trying to load the viewer before the element exists? (But I'd expect an error, unless WebViewer hides it.) Please tell us more about your debugging. What happens when you step-by-step through the code with the debugger? Do you see an assignment to your global? Do you see the code moving past the if in loadDocViewer? Etc.

@T.J.Crowder yes, console.log(webViewerInstance.UI) verifies that UI object is accessible  and ready for use but webViewerInstance.UI.loadDocument(url) isn't doing anything

Interesting. I suggest you step through the code using the debugger (it's like turning on the lights vs. stumbling around in the dark with a console.log torch ;-) ). In particular I would check that the getElementById is returning an element vs returning null because it doesn't exist yet.


But I don't want to initialize a new webViewer every function

In that case, i recommend you save the promise to a variable and reuse it:
let promise;
function loadDocViewer(url) {
  if (!promise) {
    promise = WebViewer(
      { path: "/@pdftron/webviewer/public" },
      document.getElementById("doc-viewer"),
    );
  }

  return promise
    .then((instance) => {
      return instance.UI.loadDocument(url);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error initializing WebViewer:", error);
    });
}

The first time loadDocViewer runs it will create the promise and then have to wait a little for it to resolve. Subsequent times will not have to wait since the promise is already resolved.

This is a better approach in any case, even if what the OP tried was working. I do still wonder what was going wrong for them given the absense of error, but this is still the better way.

ok, this method works when calling the function for the first time but after pdf is loaded when calling the function again with a different URL, it clears the first loaded pdf but doesn't load the new URLs pdf

@seriously - That suggests the WebViewer you're using isn't designed to be reused like that. (Or it needs you to do something other than just call loadDocument a second time.)

Since the WebViewer constructor is asynchronous, you will want to wait for WebViewer to fully resolve before calling your loadDocViewer function.
See this guide for reference:
https://docs.apryse.com/documentation/web/guides/events/loading-events/#webviewer-promise-ready-event
